# Should class IOException in Java have been an unchecked RuntimeException?

Tags: java, exception

Do you agree that the designers of Java class `java.io.IOException` should have made it an unchecked run-time exception derived from `java.lang.RuntimeException` instead of a checked exception derived only from `java.lang.Exception`?

I think that class `IOException` should have been an unchecked exception because there is little that an application can do to resolve problems like file system errors.  However, 
in [When You Can't Throw An Exception](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ce/index.html), [Elliotte Rusty Harold](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ce/index.html#author1) claims that most I/O errors are transient and so you can retry an I/O operation several times before giving up:

> For instance, an IOComparator might
>   not take an I/O error lying down, but
>   — because many I/O problems are
>   transient — you can retry a few times,
>   as shown in Listing 7:

Is this generally the case?  Can a Java application correct I/O errors or wait for the system to recover?  If so, then it is reasonable for IOException to be checked, but if it is not the case, then IOException should be unchecked so that business logic can delegate handling of this exception to a separate system error handler.

Comment: Many people think that EVERY exception should have been unchecked...

Comment: Many people need to consider which exceptions they WANT to know might happen.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: I doubt it's a coincidence that no other language has copied the chekced exception model. It was an interesting experiment, sounds good in theory, but does far more harm than good in practice.

Comment: @Michael, I do not agree, but I also think it is a matter of taste.  Based on my personal experiences I have reached the conclusion that checked exceptions simply make more robust code, as the error handling gets baked in by the original developer while writing the code, instead of being deferred to later usually ending up being a global catch-all loop.  If you don't like the checked exceptions then wrap them in a RuntimeException (and use the message to tell the person reading the log why you chose to do so).

Comment: @Michael, additionally I believe that very few languages get designed by as competent and experienced persons as Gosling and Steele, AND that they came from the LISP'y side.  Most other, especially Hejlsberg, came from the C/Pascal side.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: How ironic then that by now, C# has far more LISP-like features than Java...

Comment: @Michael, anonymous functions are nice.  Do you agree on the bakedness of error handling?

Comment: @Thorbjørn: no - it just messes up the code for everyone in order to increase the chance of correct error handling in the few cases where it can be done close to the point of occurrence.

Comment: The debate about Java exceptions continues in http://beust.com/weblog/2010/04/25/improving-exceptions/ and http://cafe.elharo.com/programming/bruce-eckel-is-wrong/.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I completely disagree. To me the model is correct. A RuntimeException is one which most typically denotes a serious error in the logic of the programming (such as ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, NullPointer, or IllegalArgument) or something that the runtime has otherwise determined really shouldn't be happening (such as SecurityException).

Conversely IOException and its derivatives are exceptions that could reasonably occur during normal execution of a program, and common logic would dictate that either those problems should be dealt with, or at least the programmer should be aware that they can occur. For example with Files if your application logger can't write its data would you rather be forced to catch a potential IOException and recover, or have something that may not be critical to your app bring down the whole JVM because no one thought to catch the unchecked Exception (as you may have guessed, I'll choose the former).

I think that there are many situations in which an IOException is either recoverable, or at the least the programmer should be explicitly aware of the potential so that if it is not recoverable the system might be able to crash more "gently".

As far your thought of if the system can not recover there are always alternatives with a checked exception. You can always have your methods declare it in their throws, throw a runtime exception of their own or crash the JVM violently:

```
public void doit() throws IOException {
  try{
  }catch(IOException e){
    // try to recover
    ...

    // can't recover
    throw e;
  }
}

public void doit() {
  try{
  }catch(IOException e){
    // try to recover
    ...

    // can't recover
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}



public void doit() {
  try{
  }catch(IOException e){
    // try to recover
    ...

    // OH NO!!!!
    System.exit(Constant.UNRECOVERABLE_IO_ERROR);
  }
}
```

Comment: In http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/dev2arch/2006/11/effective-exceptions.html, Barry Ruzek disagrees: "An I/O failure is a serious but extremely rare event. On top of that, there is usually nothing your code can do to recover from one." According to Ruzek, many Java libraries throw this exception, which suggests that they follow your first approach to recovering from an `IOException`.  However, if some method fails to recover from an `IOException`, what's the point of throwing it higher when it's unlikely that the client could recover anyway?

Comment: I disagree with "extremely rare" events. Consider a network socket. It is completely reasonable for a client Socket to become disconnected and if you are trying to write or read data this will cause an IOException. For recovery I think you need to be careful about your definition of "recovery". In the socket example you may lose the client connection, but recovery may be a process such as freeing resources that were used by the severed connection. Similarly for rethrowing you may want to log the event close to the originator, but allow something higher up the stack to deal with it.

Comment: So in what case would you advise re-throwing a `RuntimeException` after recovery fails?  Isn't this little different than (and just as bad as) an unchecked `IOException`?

Comment: EOFException is not 'extremely rare'. It is expected once per connection. And exceptions aren't part of a recovery model anyway - see the extensive discussion in Stroustrup's writings.

I completely agree with M. Jessup on this. Fortunately the question is moot as Java is a done deal.

Comment: @Derek I am not advocating the rethrow of a RuntimeException. I merely provided that as an example of how one could "simulate" an IOException as being unchecked if for some reason that is desired behavior (which I can't think of a reasonable example where it would be). Similarly for using System.exit as an alternative for failed recovery (perhaps I should have also included the sarcastic "//OH NO!!!!!" for the RuntimeException example). In any case I believe the proper strategy is to catch, attempt to recover if possible, and then rethrow, or return an appropriate value from the method.

Comment: @EJP: Yes, the Java libraries are a done deal, but the design of Java's exception model and libraries can instruct the proper design of new Java libraries and the exception model of new languages that run on the JVM.  For example, the Spring Framework believes that, "Checked exceptions are overused in Java. A platform shouldn't force you to catch exceptions you're unlikely to be able to recover from."  Scala, a relatively new language that runs on the JVM, does not support checked exceptions.  Is this for better or worse?

Comment: What am I being asked here? I've stated my position and by implication I disagree with the counter-position.

Comment: @EJP: My question about Scala was mostly rhetorical. My point was that even though Java is a "done deal", the question is not entirely moot.  It's still useful to discuss retrospectively about the whether the original Java design decisions were appropriate so that we may avoid repeating any mistakes in future Java libraries or JVM languages, like Scala.

Comment: @EJP: In http://beust.com/weblog/2010/04/25/improving-exceptions/, Cédric Beust, creator of TestNG, does not consider the question moot, either: "In the future, I’d like to see discussions on this topic focused more on where and when to use checked exceptions and runtime exceptions instead of reading articles telling you that you should always do "this" and never do "that"."

Comment: Again I still don't know what I'm being asked, or told, here. IOException is a checked exception in Java. Period. I like it that way and indeed I like checked exceptions. You are free to disagree but then it ceases to be a question about Java. EOFException has to be dealt with once per connection unless you are using lower-level I/O methods, so making it a RuntimeException doesn't make sense.

Comment: not agree with the initial answer, in most cases checked exceptions are not needed. and lots of new languages already do not use those. and this is good.

Comment: I disagree, checked exceptions should be well defined business code paths. All exceptions related to the IO devices are unexpected

Answer (score 29):

I know it has been 4 years since this question was asked but an [UncheckedIOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/UncheckedIOException.html) was added in Java 8.

Comment: The Java 8 API designers must have read my question!  In hindsight, I should have invented `UncheckIOException` myself and copyrighted the API so that Oracle would have had to pay me license fees. :)

Answer (score 11):

I think it is clever to leave it a checked exception. I regard runtime exceptions as **bugs**, and this is clearly not the case. Recovery by retry is sometimes possible, and also some IOException messages can be informative to the end user (e.g. no permissions to write, not enough disk space, etc).

Comment: I regard checked exceptions as a **bug** in the language design. You say it yourself: an IOExcpetion message can be informative to the user - but what good is that to the low-level IO method that has no business with the UI and yet is forced to catch the exception or pollute its signature with it?

Comment: Michael, do you mean the low-level I/O method is forced to catch the exception and pollute its signature, or the UI level code?

Comment: @Michael: IMO the signature is not polluted at all. Just as you specify the returned value type, you should also specify other kind of legitimate outcomes of the action. It has both a practical and a declarative importance.

Comment: @Derek: I meant the low-level IO code. @Eyal: that's the theory. In practice, it results in horribly leaky abstractions and massively polluted APIs - because we're not talking about just that one method, but everything between it and the point where the exception is finally caught, for every method from which it is called. And the same for every other method that throws checked exceptions.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: IMHO, checked exceptions would have been an excellent feature if the distinction were not rigidly tied to the exception type, but rather to method definitions, invocations, throw sites, and catch sites, and if individual *instances* could be "expected" or "unexpected".  If a method is "expected" to throw an exception, then a caller should have to catch the exception, explicitly pass it on as "expected", or else declare that it was "unexpected".  Catch statements should then be able to either catch only "expected" exceptions, or accept unexpected ones as well.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: Within the existing framework, something almost as good could be achieved if there were a concise syntax for marking a method or block with `doesntExpect(IOException) {...code...}` which would translate almost as `try {...code...} catch(IOException ex) {throw new UnexpectedException(ex);};`, but which would not catch exceptions thrown by `throw` statements within the block [as distinct from those thrown by nested method calls or implicitly by operations].  The Runtime would have no trouble handling such try/catch constructs if the compiler could generate them.

Answer (score 5):

Probably the vast majority of IO exceptions are recoverable - permissions errors, lack of space on the drive, connection closed, etc, etc. I believe unchecked exceptions are supposed to be used for "there's no reasonable way to recover from this" sorts of situations.

Answer (score 4):

No because you can recover from some IOExceptions.  Most notable ones are low level indexed reads and writes.  If it fails, sometimes you can just retry without harm.

Answer (score 4):

In a well-designed exception framework, a distinction should be made between exceptions which are to some extent "expected" and those which are not.  Java attempts to use checked versus unchecked exceptions for this.  By that standard, IOException should be a checked exception.

A fundamental problem, though, is that oftentimes code will be written with a (perhaps reasonable) expectation that a certain exception will not occur, and nothing can usefully be done to handle it if it does.  If a method is declared as throwing a particular checked exception, Java allows its caller to ignore the exception if it declares itself as throwing that exception, but there's no means by which a method or code block can specify that certain exceptions from called methods *are not expected to occur*.  A common anti-pattern is:

```
try
{
  methodThatsDeclaredAsThrowingFooExceptionButWont()
}
catch FooException Ex
{
  // Never going to happen
}
```

The apparent assumption is that since the method won't throw FooException and the only reason the `catch` is there is to make the compiler happy, there's no reason for the `catch` to do anything.  Insidious, because if a `FooException` does get thrown, for whatever reason, it will go undetected.

An alternative is for a method which calls methodThatsDeclaredAsThrowingFooExceptionButWont to declare itself as `throws FooException` or `throws Exception`, but that isn't really appropriate either.  If a method which is not expected to throw a `FooException` does, the system state is apt to be different from what it would be expected when a `FooException` is thrown.

For example, suppose one attempts to load a document, but the document-load routine needs to read some non-document-specific translation tables which are supposed to be stored at a fixed location; if that attempt fails, having the `IOException` percolate up to the caller would imply that there was a problem loading the document being loaded.  If the load-document routine isn't prepared to sensibly handle the possibility that the load-translation-tables routine might fail, such failure shouldn't percolate up the same way as would an `IOException` that occurred while actually loading the document.

The proper remedy would not be for `IOException` to be an unchecked exception, but rather for there to be a declarative means by which code could indicate that one or more kinds of checked exceptions should not be allowed to percolate out of a certain block from methods called thereby, but should instead be wrapped in some other exception type (e.g. RuntimeException).

Comment: I have my IDE's auto-inserted catch block body set to `throw new RuntimeException(${EXCEPTION});`