# Should unchecked exceptions be caught and dealt with?

Tags: java, unchecked-exception

I have been reading many posts about exceptions lately and I have a question whether unchecked exceptions should be caught. I have read that if you want your application to recover from an error you use checked exceptions. However if you can't deal with the checked exception you either wrap it into another checked exception so you can pass it to another layer; for instance you wrap an `SqlException`, or you throw an unchecked exception. However, should you catch unchecked exceptions? Are unchecked exceptions ideally programming errors that you don't check for? Should they just bubble up from your application?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Should unchecked exceptions be caught and dealt with?

The answer is that it depends:

- It depends on what the exception is.
- It depends on why the exception was thrown.  Was it "expected"?  Was it due to a bug, or bad input, or an environmental problem?  Or something else?
- It depends if there is a good way to recover.  That typically depends in part on the previous criteria.

If the exception is unexpected, the cause of the exception is uncertain, and / or if there is no sound recovery strategy if you do catch the exception, then it is generally better to allow the exception to bubble up, and make sure that it gets reported / logged at the top level.

And if the exception is an `Error`, the general rule is that you should NOT attempt to recover.  And that includes `StackOverflowError` and (particularly) `OutOfMemoryError`.  The `Error` exceptions indicate a problem that is difficult (or impossible) to safely recover from, and the best strategy is to allow or cause the application to exit.

---

> What do you mean by reported/logged at the top level? Do you mean catching it at the UI layer for instance and show an dialog, log it etc?

I mean that the exception and its stack trace should be written to the application's log file so that the evidence of the problem is available for the maintainers to look at.  Whether you also try to explain the problem to the end user (and how you do that) is a separate issue.

The "top level" may be the "main" method, a child thread or runnable's "run" method ... or an uncaught exception handler.  Basically it is wherever the exception eventually will "bubble up" to if it is not caught.  Details will depend on your application's architecture.

Answer (score 5):

You should catch an exception — checked or unchecked — if you can handle it in a meaningful way to recover from the problem.  You generally should *not* catch an exception if you don't have a good way to handle it.

I've seen too much code that "handles" exceptions by doing `e.printStackTrace()` and then continuing as if nothing was wrong.  Ignoring a problem like that usually just leads to other problems later.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing forbids you from catching runtime exceptions.

The trend, nowadays, is to use more and more runtime exceptions, and less and less checked exceptions. Spring, Hibernate, and the latest Java EE specs use runtime exceptions almost exclusively. This makes the business code easier to read and less cumbersome.

The runtime exceptions are generally intended to be not caught at all, or only caught at the bottom of the call stack, in the UI layer, in order to display an error message, because that's usually the only thing you can do when such an exception occurs.

Comment: Ah, that make sense, only catch them at UI layer and show an error.

Answer (score 1):

The basic difference between the `Checked` and `Unchecked` Exception is that, you need to explicitly handle the former or propagate it in the `inheritance hierarchy`, while this is not required for the later.

Also, `CheckedException` extend from `java.lang.Exception`, while `UncheckedExceptions` extend from `java.lang.RuntimeException`, which are not needed to be handled. Note that, `RuntimeException` are themselves a subclass of `Exception`.

Given, all the information above, if you `handle` an `unchecked exception` then its fine. It will work fine, and the control will go to the corresponding `catch` block. But you shouldn't do it. Unless, you really need it and you have a proper way to handle them.

- **For e.g: -** You should handle an `IllegalArgumentException` which is
  an `Unchecked Exception`.
- And then, you shouldn't handle errors like: - `StackOverflowError`. As, you don't know why that problem might have occurred, and what could be an appropriate way to handle it. So, just leave it to the JVM. `Errors` are `Unchecked Exception` that you cannot recover from.

For more details, refer these links: -

- http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/checked-or-unchecked-exceptions.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Comment: i know this is old so sorry but i need to ask - why do we need to handle IllegalArgumentException - does this not indicate programmer error and in fact if we read the documnetation of the method that throws it we should identifty the correct parameter to pass before actually passing it?

Comment: It's somewhat related to logical errors that might result in ill-functioning of your code. For e.g. you would not want your user to pass a negative number to a method that calculates the `sqrt`, in which case, you would add a test at the beginning, and if negative number is found, you would like to inform the user about this, possibly by throwing an exception saying the argument passed is illegal.

Answer (score 1):

Choice for checked exceptions is usually: you just add it to `throws` if you can't do anything about it, `catch` and convert it to new exception with original as the cause if you can't do anything useful about it but can add information, and `catch` it and do something about it if it is feasible and also *the right place* in your code to do something about it.

Unchecked exceptions are a bit more tricky. In the *ideal* world, they should indicate programming/logic errors, and be handled pretty much like assertion failure, not caught and especially not swallowed.

Some unchecked exception coming from Java standard library or other libraries should in my opinion really be checked exceptions, but are not. These are cases, where the caller should acknowledge that such exceptions may be passing through them even if they don't `catch` them. For unchecked exceptions that could as well be checked exceptions, basically same rules: catch them if you want to do something about them, otherwise let them bubble up. If you are making a library (even if it's just internal to an application), and an unchecked exception really is something which should be caught later, then you may want to catch and re-throw it wrapped into a checked exception in the library code.

In general, try to avoid having unchecked exceptions thrown. Check the input, so you don't need to `catch`, and if exception is still thrown, then it's a bug and should be left uncaught. Only `catch` them if it is the only or at least clearly the best way.

To be fair to Java libraries, the language was designed in the era, when IDEs didn't yet immediately complain about missing throws clauses and offer to fill them in automatically, so making them unchecked may have been justified by reducing burden on developer. But with modern tools, there's really no excuse.

And then, as mentioned in other answers, there are unchecked exceptions you should *not* catch.

Comment: In most cases, "acknowledging that certain exceptions may be passing through" is the wrong thing to do; it's unfortunate that it's also the easiest way to deal with checked exceptions.  The problem is that if `foo` calls `bar`, and `bar` throws a checked exception `moo` which `foo` wasn't prepared to deal with, there will now be two problems for the caller to deal with: (1) an exception of type `moo` will have been thrown and not caught; (2) the execution of `foo` will have been interrupted in an unexpected place.  In many cases, the latter problem may actually be the more severe one...

Comment: ...but the exception system offers no convenient way for `foo` to indicate that.  A semantically cleaner pattern would be for `foo` to catch unexpected checked exceptions and throw them as unchecked exceptions, but that's awkward; further, if a `FileNotFoundException` occurs, it would be nicer to report it as a `FileNotFoundException` than as an `UnexpectedException`.

Comment: @supercat I'm not sure what you mean, but "Unexpected checked exception" sounds like an oxymoron to me. If programmer of `foo` fails to account for any checked exceptions from method it calls, that's a bug. And by "account for" I mean, for example, using the "try-with-resources" for IO, etc.

Comment: If a certain method call couldn't possibly throw a certain exception unless a data structure was corrupted beyond repair or the method grossly violated its contract, error-handling code surrounding that exception may not serve much purpose.  As an example, suppose a method is supposed to create a bitmap object based on a "BitmapSourceInfo" object that can either supply a filename or an array of pixel data.  If the source-info object might supply a filename, then the method should be expected to throw `IOException`.  if the caller creates a `BitmapSourceInfo` object...

Comment: ...containing an array of pixels data, however, and the `LoadBitmap` method promises not to throw an exception when bitmap data is supplied in an array, the caller should not be expected to cleanly handle an `IOException` thrown by the method.  Further, even if the code which called `LoadBitMap` was expected to possibly throw `IOException` for other reasons, an `IOException` was thrown while supposedly copying data from an array would not represent a condition expected by the caller, and thus shouldn't percolate up as such a type.

Comment: I think, first of all, the level of code where it is known no exception (of some type or at all) should happen turns checked exceptions to runtime errors. It is a bit of (mostly IDE-generated) boilerplate but not much and will be great help in debugging if it is ever triggered. Then, typically there would be a custom exception class to go with as generic thing as `BitmapSourceInfo` sounds like, so code using it would only need to care about single exception type (it might also be just plain `throws IOException` and using subclasses of it, depending on design details).

Comment: I think we're in agreement that unexpected checked exceptions should be escalated to `RuntimeException`; that was largely my point. If only a small minority of the usage scenarios for a method could ever cause it to throw a particular exception, declaring the exception "checked" will force most callers to add useless boilerplate.  The boilerplate wouldn't be huge, but it would be widespread.  Even though declaring an exception as "unchecked" might tend to imply that most of the *places* where it might theoretically be thrown would be unable to handle it, it's entirely possible that...

Comment: ...the only places where the exception would *actually* get thrown would be able to deal with it.  It would be entirely proper for the code in such places to catch and deal with the exception, despite its being "unchecked".

Answer (score -1):

> should you catch unchecked exceptions?

Yes and No. Depends on what exception is thrown.

> Are unchecked exceptions ideally programming errors that you don't check for?

You can write a `catch` block to catch unchecked exception but **again depends whether you should**. If you do then it's possible that a bug remain unsolved for a long time and by the time it is discovered it's size is also changed.

> Should they just bubble up from your application?

If they occur, try to solve their cause (if it' spossible). Don't `catch` them always as Hard and Fast rule.

Comment: `InputFormatException` from a `Scanner` is unchecked, not rare and should be recovered.

Comment: The same applies to any other `IOException`

Comment: did you mean `IllegalArgumentException`?

Comment: Suggest a way to use the `Scanner` without triggering `IllegarArgumentException`s.

Comment: Do you know how Sun calls `UncheckedException`s that should not be recovered? They are called `Error`s. Pretty much any other unchecked should be recovered if anticipated.

Comment: `IOException` is definitely a checked exception.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: if an exception is anticipated, i'll prefer to avoid it at all instead of having a catch for it to recover.

Comment: How come `IOException` became an `Unchecked` one?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sorry about that. They still deserve recovery ;-)

Comment: @Azodious I'm still wondering how do you want to avoid `IllegalArgumentException`s from `Scanner#nextInt()`

Comment: @JanDvorak: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624145/should-class-ioexception-in-java-have-been-an-unchecked-runtimeexception

Comment: @JanDvorak: I wrote if possible, should be avoided. if not then have to be caught.

Comment: @Azodious I agree with that - expections [sic] should be avoided, not caught. The downvote's not mine, by the way ;-)